# How to read specific characters in a cell which consists of numeric and text values?

Tags: matlab

I want to read (in matlab) specific characters from a cell which contains a mixture of numbers and texts. How can i do that in matlab? Could anybody help me with codes, please.

Here is the example:

---

r1200i000-0ln140010.LID

This represents a file name in a cell. I have more than 100000 rows in single column. I want to read the 14th and 15 th character (here is 14) and write this value in a different column in the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of the string (the contents of the cell) as an array of characters you can index the individual members using the (n:m) convention, i.e.

```
>> string = 'a string';
>> part = string(3:4)
st
```

Bear in mind that the output will then also be a string. If you want to use it as a number you can then use [str2num](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html).

Comment: I have used the following codes:

v = {xlsread('test data.xlsx', 'A2:A165238')};

out=cellfun(@(x) str2num(x(14:15)),v,'un',0);


Still matlab shows errors:

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> @(x)str2num(x(14:15))

Comment: Actually yes my answer above is not sufficient to deal with your case - you need to index elements of the data within each cell, for all cells. You can use a combination of curly braces and parens to do both, e.g. v{1,1}(14:15) gives the 14th to 15th characters of the string in cell {1,1} - see [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/multilevel-indexing-to-access-parts-of-cells.html) for details. It might work just to do v{1,:}(14:15) but I haven't got Matlab in front of me right now so I'll have to check later. Have a play with it though. I've changed the above answer.